# Why half-wave dipole is the most efficient one in comparison to other electrical lengths of that antenna?

Tags: antenna, dipole, vertical-antenna

I have a problem on the understanding of a half-wavelength antenna. Namely, why is the half-wave antenna has a highest power emission. Considering Far Field factor F($\theta$), which is known from the following formula:

\begin{equation}
|F(\theta)|^2= \frac{ (\cos{( \frac{kl} {2} \cos{\theta})} - \cos{ \frac{kl} {2} })^2 } {\sin^2{\theta}},
\end{equation}
where $k$ is wavenumber, $l$ is a total dipole length (two equal length wires), $\theta$ is a an angle from the antenna axis.

That factor corresponds to the wave power. It seems like , that  the highest Far field is for kl/2 = Pi. One can check that considering $\theta = 0$, and demanding the highest $|F(\theta)|^2$. By the way, the plot corresponding to different electrical length is shown on the following figure. One can see the highest $|F(\theta)|^2$ for $kl = 2\pi$.

[image: Dipole antenna Far field factor]

So could I ask you where is the problem in the latter? Should one condisder reflections of feed signal from the antenna or other things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula in the question is taken from page 44 of a book called The Theory of Electromagnetic Wave Propagation by CH Papas. The text says that the formula describes the radiation pattern for a center driven wire antenna. Radiation patterns normally show a graph of relative intensity which isn't the same thing as efficiency.

For transmitting, the efficiency of an antenna is described as the ratio between the power delivered to the antenna compared to the power radiated, and is determined mostly by the ratio of the radiation resistance to ohmic resistance, as per this formula :

$$ \eta = \frac{P_R}{P_{IN}} = \frac{R_R}{R_R+R_L} $$

The graph in the question it seems just shows the difference in the main lobes of the radiation patterns for antennas of different wavelengths. A full wave dipole does not have higher efficiency than a half wave dipole, and the length in wavelengths of an antenna doesn't determine its efficiency.

Comment: Agree with that. This is only radiation pattern and do not say anything about the efficiency. The point is that one can take the pointing vector which is a factor multiplied by a radiation pattern. And in order to calculate directivity, one should divide the Pointing vector module on the $P_{iso}$ - the power from the equivalent isotropic radiator. The latter is calculated from $P_{iso} = \frac{P_{TRP}} {4\pi r^2}$ where $P_{TRP}$ is total radiated power and integrated pointing vector over a Sphere.

Comment: That book is a classic, Andrew, what do you think?

Comment: Ah yes, i can see from your formula that there is only energy integrated included. Thank you

Comment: It seems that I just misunderstood the efficiency

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the correct answer or not: At varying electric lengths, at any moment in time, one part of the antenna is producing the wanted field(s) and another part might be producing a canceling field(s). With a half wavelength, all you get is the wanted field and no canceling field. The canceling field (I call it that because it works against the main field) is what creates lobes and direction. A full wavelength would be the worst because the top half of the antenna essentially cancels out the bottom half.

[image]

Comment: technical words: constructive and destructive interference

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation. Should it be true for two wavelength dipole antenna? If antenna centrally feed, the current is basically asymmetric around the center. I want to say it is $I_0 sin(k(l/2-|z|))$. So, there is no annihilating current nodes for one wavelength antenna, while two wavelength one, there are.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter if the antenna is fed from the center or from the end, you can probably think of it as a wire in space that is oscillating "magically" let's say, and then just focus on the voltage and current distribution. With the half-wave there is one place in the center with current, with a full-wave there are 2 places with current that oppose each other, and with 2 full-waves there are 4 places of current, 2 oppose the other 2. It's best to draw this, let me add a drawing to the answer regarding this comment.

Comment: Sorry I can't comment on the math you posted, I don't understand math :D

Comment: This answer has some interesting ideas but is technically incorrect, the applied sine wave source at the feed points results in a current distribution along the antenna elements which completely determines the radiation pattern, both positive and negative current flow contribute to antenna output, one does not cancel out the other, it just happens that a half wave length isn't long enough to allow for both positive and negative current. The terms constructive and destructive do not apply here, these terms are used to explain what happens when two wave forms add together.

Comment: The positive and negative halves of a sine wave don't work against each other, both form part of the mechanism which produces an output from the antenna.

Comment: @Andrew the antenna fixes the current distribution like a string on a guitar. if you feed it from the center you need current and if you feed it from the end you need voltage, plus everything in-between. i don't see how positive and negative currents wouldn't cancel out.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the antenna studied in CH Papas book is centrally feed. The antenna drawn on the picture by @Jack0220 corresponds to a $\approx$ "monopole", if it is a proper naming for that, however current should be different.  The current distribution is not the same for those antennas. In case of central feed the current is given in the center of antenna and should be continuous. I do not know how to add a plot here, but you imagine take a middle of center of middle or right figure and then mirror it to the right. This is what formula $ I_0sin(k(l/2−|z|)).$ says

Comment: By the way, as for me the current will have opposite nodes when taking into account 2 wave antenna. And the opposite currents will create oposite electric and magnetic field  at $\theta = 0$ at far field.

Comment: Otherwise, it might be possible to have an antenna drawn by @Jack0220 when taking two monopoles, each having different feed (I am guessing)

Comment: @PetrPolovodov i updated the drawing. i didn't add the feed points in the drawing. if they are fed at a max current such as center for 1/2 λ a high current is needed to drive the antenna, if fed at max voltage such as at the end of any of these or center of 1 λ and 2 λ plus additional locations, then a high voltage is needed to drive the antenna. when looking at the fundamental frequency of oscillation there can only be one regardless of from where it is fed (i think but i'm not 100% sure).

Comment: It should be the same concept as from where you pluck a string on a guitar, if you plug it at the end you need more force and less displacement and at the center (for 1/2 λ) you need less force and more displacement.

Comment: By the end, i mean almost at the end. I'm pretty sure even a true 1/2 λ (or 1 λ etc.) antenna cannot be fed from the electrical perfect end because the impedance is infinite, same as you couldn't plug a guitar string from the point where it is actually fixed in place, you'd have to go right before that to have a chance at "feeding it" (disclaimer: i think so).

Comment: @PetrPolovodov i think I'm wrong about something. when the full-wave is center fed, i suppose the current from one leg will still line up with the other, not what i drew.

Comment: i'm not sure if i'm allowed to post videos, but this one is a really good explanation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RF5r64fmFhU

Comment: @Jack0220,  it is actualy is written in the formula I wrote. The current distribution

Comment: @Jack0220 thank you for the video

Answer (score 1):

It isn't.

1. Gain in the broadside (θ=0) direction isn't "efficiency".
2. A half-wave dipole doesn't maximize that parameter, even among dipoles; it increases until roughly 1.25 wavelengths, then decreases, then generally increases again, in an oscillating way.

There are nice things about half-wave dipoles (a convenient, easily-matched impedance and a simple pattern without lobes), but it doesn't maximize gain or directivity or anything like that.

Comment: It seems like that a one wavelength dipole is more directive then a halfwave antenna. Also, I understand that the pattern of half wave dipole is for broad angles.